# How do you make the UISearchBar translucent?

Tags: iphone, search, ios7

On iOS 7, setting the UISearchBar to be translucent isn't making the search bar translucent. Is there anything I'm not understanding it? I'm adding it to a UIViewController that is part of a UINavigationController. There's a UITableView aligning to the Top Layout Guide. The navigation bar is fine and has translucency, but the search bar is a solid color for some reason.

Comment: share the screenshot of ur view in which UISearch bar is shown.

Answer (score 3):

See the new `.searchBarStyle` property on UISearchBar. I suspect `UISearchBarStyleMinimal` is what you're after.